# Is there a better way?

Tags: c#, .net, file

Is there a better way to do this.

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo("C://notebook.txt");`

public bool Archived
        {
            get
            {
                return (((File.GetAttributes(f.FullName)) 
                        & FileAttributes.Archive) == FileAttributes.Archive);
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == true)
                {
                    if (!this.Archived)
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(f.FullName, 
                        File.GetAttributes(f.FullName) | FileAttributes.Archive);
                    }
                }
                else if (value == false)
                {
                    if (this.Archived)
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(f.FullName, 
                        File.GetAttributes(f.FullName) 
                        & ~FileAttributes.Archive);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

`

Comment: Well, yeah, keep it DRY.

Comment: And *what* are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, you can edit if (value == true) else if (value == false).  That's nails on a black board.

Comment: But Hans, what if value == FileNotFound? :)

Comment: By the way, using "//" in your file path string is incorrect.  Backslashes need to be escaped, not forward slashes.  And Windows paths use backslashes.  Should be `FileInfo f = new FileInfo("C:\\notebook.txt");`

Comment: @Jacob: +1 Although in UNIX-like systems (don't know about Windows) multiple `////` are converted to single `/` when used in file paths, so it would still work.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as you have a `FileInfo` object you can use it's `Attributes` property instead of using the `File.GetAttributes` and `File.SetAttributes` methods:

```
public bool Archived {
  get {
    return (f.Attributes & FileAttributes.Archive) != 0;
  }
  set {
    if (value) {
      if (!this.Archived) {
        f.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Archive;
      }
    } else {
      if (this.Archived) {
        f.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Archive;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always start by simplifying the way you handle the `value` in the setter. Then you could avoid a double-get by reading the attributes at the top of the setter.

```
    public bool Archived
        {
            get
            {
                return (((File.GetAttributes(f.FullName)) & FileAttributes.Archive) != 0);
            }
            set
            {
                var attributes = File.GetAttributes(f.FullName);
                bool archived = ((attributes & FileAttributes.Archive) != 0);

                if (value)
                {
                    if (!archived)
                        File.SetAttributes(f.FullName, attributes | FileAttributes.Archive);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (archived)
                        File.SetAttributes(f.FullName, attributes & ~FileAttributes.Archive);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, Guffa has a point about the attributes being cached by `FileInfo`, though I see this more as an argument against using `FileInfo` in the first place. I'd prefer to store just the pathname as a string.

I also changed the bit test to compare to zero, which I should have done in the first place. Thanks, KeithS and Guffa.

And, to keep it all in one place, if we were using C# 4.0, we could say:

```
bool archived = attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Archive);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that's pretty standard when dealing with flagged (bitwise rather) values.

You might wanna lose the `else if` bit, as booleans generally only have 2 states.

Answer (score 0):

In the getter, if the bitwise AND evaluates to any nonzero, the bit's set, so your getter can be shortened somewhat:

```
get
{
   return (((File.GetAttributes(f.FullName)) & FileAttributes.Archive) != 0);
}
```

Everything else is pretty much optimal; you can lose some parenthesis and one evaluation by getting rid of the braces around the if and else of the setter, and making the "else if" just an "else". Or, combine the inner and outer expressions; really, the inner expressions are not necessary as 1 | 1 == 1 and 1 & ~1 == 0, so setting it to the same value multiple times won't hurt anything.

Comment: Thanks I "borrowed" that from you (and Guffa). If we knew this was C# 4.0, we could also do: `bool archived = attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Archive);`